# How to check if a<b bitwise?

Tags: logic

How to check if two numbers, `a is less than or equal to b bitwise`?

For example, how to check if `2 <= 3` using bitwise operator

**Edit: a and b are in decimals. So, given any two numbers a and b, can I use bitwise operators like &,^,|,~, to infer if a is <= b?**

Comment: Lexicographically?

Comment: What do you mean check? You want to know whether all bits of $(10)_2$ are less than those of $(11)_2$? If the number is given in binary, you should just check the pairs of bits one after the other. If not, then it is probably easier to just convert both to binary than to pull some clever trick.

Comment: not specifically. I simply mean, if I any have 2 numbers, a and b, can I use bitwise operators like &,|,^ to infer in a<=b.

Comment: Oh, you mean bitwise comparing two numbers given in binary. That's easy: a<b if you find a 0 in a where a 1 is in b as you sweep left to right. This assumes the length is the same but does not assume that numbers start with a $1$. If the numbers are different lengths but numbers all start with $1$ then the longer number is bigger. If you can't assume either of these for some reason, then you should trim the longer number left to right until you either hit a $1$ or get to the same length as the shorter number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to check whether or not $a < b$ using **only** bitwise operations on $a$ and $b$, because checking whether or not $a < b$ involves comparing different bit positions to each other, and bitwise operations cannot do this.

However, $a < b$ whenever the leftmost 1 in ($b$ AND NOT $a$) is further left than the leftmost 1 in ($a$ AND NOT $b$).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two numbers to be positive.

Check from the most significant bit to the least significant bit (perhaps using bitmask), the first moment when the bits differ, the one with the $1$ bit is larger than the one with $0$ bit.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to make a few other assumptions. Here is one thing you can do.

Assume that all bitstrings $s$ are of a finite length $n$, and so where bit $s_i$ represents $2^i$, all bitstrings $s$ are of the form

$$s=s_{n-1}s_{n-2}...s_2s_1s_0$$

So, for example, let $n=8$. Then where $a$ is the binary number representing the number $2$, $a=00000010$, where $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$, and $a_i=0$ for all $i$ ranging from $2$ though $7$.

OK, now you can use the following logical formula:

$\forall a \forall b (a \le b \leftrightarrow ((\forall 0 \le i < n : a(i)=b(i)) \lor \exists j (b(j)=1 \land a(j) = 0 \land \forall i (i > j \rightarrow a(i) = b(i))))$

Of course, that still contains quantifiers, as well as mathematical operations $<$ and $\le$ (which could be a real put-off given as you trying to *define* $\le$), but at least it does contain bitwise logical operators.  Does this help?

Comment: You wrote s the first time where you meant a.

Comment: Oh!  Did you fix it? Thanks!!

Comment: Nope. Check the fourth paragraph.

Comment: Ah. I actually do mean to use $s$ there, for I want this to be a statement about bitstrings in general. But clearly I should make that more clear.

Comment: Oh, I see; I think it would be clearer in math notation to have something like $b(s,i)$.

Comment: @Ian How about $s_i$?  That is, if I say that any bitstring looks like $s=s_{n-1}s_{n-2}....s_2s_1s_0$ ... would that be acceptable?

Comment: That's a little better I suppose.

Comment: @Ian OK, I'll change it to that then. I just don;t want to get too caught up in that specific when in my main formula I want to focus to be on the bit-wise comparison.